# Selector.select do not block as expected

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, nio

In my current project I notice that `select()` do not block as expected.
It do not block at all and return always, even when no IO was present. So I got a busy cpu.

The registration will always invoked by another thread, so I need the lock and the wakeup.

The doc says for `selectNow()`:

> Invoking this method clears the effect of any previous invocations of the wakeup method.

So I invoke the method at the end of each iteration. no succsess.
I found no example or explanation how to use `selectNow` for my purpose.

What is wrong with the code?

---

Here is my example code, so you can test this.

BTW: Another stackoverflow question was the rolemodel of my code.
EDIT: Example fixed! It works now.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Test implements Runnable {
    ReentrantLock selectorLock = new ReentrantLock();
    Selector selector;
    boolean alive;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        SelectionKey key;
        Iterator<SelectionKey> keys;

        alive = true;
        try {
            while (alive) {
                selectorLock.lock();
                selectorLock.unlock();

                selector.select();
                System.out.println("select() returned");

                keys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
                // handle each "event"
                while (keys.hasNext()) {
                    key = keys.next();
                    // mark as handled
                    keys.remove();
                    // handle
                    handleKey(key);
                }
                //selector.selectNow(); // don't fix this
            }
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void handleKey(SelectionKey key)
        throws IOException {
        SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        if (key.isConnectable()) {
            System.out.println("connecting");
            if ( channel.finishConnect() ) {
                key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
            } else {
                key.cancel();
            }
        } else if (key.isReadable()) {
            System.out.println("reading");
            // read and detect remote close
            channel.read(ByteBuffer.allocate(64));
        }
    }

    public void register(SelectableChannel channel, int ops, Object attachment)
        throws ClosedChannelException {
        selectorLock.lock();
        try {
            System.out.println("wakeup");
            selector.wakeup();
            channel.register(selector, ops, attachment);
        } finally {
            selectorLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public Test()
        throws IOException {
        selector = Selector.open();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException {
        Test t = new Test();
        new Thread(t).start();

        SocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8080);
        SocketChannel channel = SocketChannel.open();
        channel.configureBlocking(false);
        channel.connect(address);

        t.register(channel, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT, "test channel attachment");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't register `OP_READ` until `OP_CONNECT` has fired *and* `finishConnect()` has returned 'true'. At that point you must deregister `OP_CONNECT`.

Similarly don't register channels for OP_WRITE until you have something to write. `OP_WRITE` is always ready except when the socket send buffer is full, so it should only be registered *after* you have detected that condition (`write()` returns zero), and you should de-register it immediately it fires (unless the condition happens again).

And finally `OP_CONNECT` and `OP_WRITE` are the same thing under the hood, which given what I've just said about `OP_WRITE` explains your selector spins.

Comment: Thank you. Your hint fixed the issue.
I change `handleKey`.

Comment: How do you deregister? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13867557/2760299

Comment: You can deregister a specific OP_* by calling the interestOps method on the desired selectionKey setting it with what you now want to be notified about. Like for example: selectionKey.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);

Comment: I contest that OP_WRITE should only be registered after detecting a short-count. It is perfectly fine and quite practical to use OP_WRITE to drive output. When you want to write, you just toggle OP_WRITE on. The selector thread will then encode + write until the buffer is empty at which point it toggles OP_WRITE off. Clean. Internally poll(2) descriptors represents OP_WRITE as just another bit in the flags. At least on *nix they are. So there is really no overhead or other reason that I can think of to using OP_WRITE to drive output.