# Is there a way to de-register a selector on a socket channel

Tags: java, sockets, select, nonblocking, socketchannel

This is a pretty straight forward question, but I have found a need to unregister a selector overlooking my socket channel for java.

```
SocketChannel client = myServer.accept(); //forks off another client socket
client.configureBlocking(false);//this channel takes in multiple request
client.register(mySelector, SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);//changed from r to rw
```

Where I can later in the program call something like

```
client.deregister(mySelector);
```

And that the selector will no longer catch data keys for that socket channel. This would make life much easier for me given my server/client design.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Call `cancel()` on the selection key:

```
SelectionKey key = client.register(mySelector,
    SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
...
key.cancel();
```

or

```
...
SelectionKey key = client.keyFor(mySelector);
key.cancel();
```

Comment: Or you could do `client.close()` as well.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @Nikolai 's answer. Doing `client.close()` will also deregister the channel.

> A key is added to its selector's cancelled-key set when it is cancelled, whether by closing its channel or by invoking its cancel method.

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html